# iOS push notification custom sound not able to figure out

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have a `UNMutableNotificationContent` object in my AppDelegate class set up like so:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "TITLE"
    content.body = "Friendly message"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
```

In my Xcode build, I have a custom sound file called Wake-up-sounds.wav, and I am trying to set content.sound equal to this sound file, but I do not know how. How do I do this?

Comment: is this a local notification or remote notification. In remote notification the sound name will be set from server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

```
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: "Wake-up-sounds.wav")
```

Apple says :

> To use the user’s preferred alert sound, use the default() method to
>   create the sound object. To specify a custom sound, **use the
>   init(named:) method**. Files for custom sounds **must be located in your
>   executable’s main bundle or in the Library/Sounds directory of your
>   app’s container directory**. Custom alert sounds are played by the
>   system sound facility, so they **must be in one of the following audio**
>   data formats: **Linear PCM MA4 (IMA/ADPCM) µLaw aLaw** You can package the
>   audio data in an **aiff, wav, or caf** file. Sound files **must be less than
>   30 seconds in length**. If the **sound file is longer than 30 seconds**, the
>   system **plays the default sound instead**

Answer (score 0):

You can add & assign custom sound to your notifications using UNNotificationSound in your extension.

> For a remote notification, assign the name of your sound file to the sound key in the aps dictionary. You can also use a notification service app extension to add a sound file to a notification shortly before delivery. In your extension, create a UNNotificationSound object and add it to your notification content in the same way that you’d for a local notification.
>
> Audio files must already be on the user’s device before the system can play them. If you use a predefined set of sounds for your notifications, include the audio files in your app’s bundle. For all other sounds, the UNNotificationSound object looks only in the following locations:
>
> - The /Library/Sounds directory of the app’s container directory.
> - The /Library/Sounds directory of one of the app’s shared group container directories.
> - The main bundle of the current executable.

Here is the official Apple Developer link: [UNNotificationSound](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound?language=objc)